# Paint Tool Sai pressure sensitivity doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, wine, wacom

Alright.  Here's the situation; I've got my Ubuntu up and running, and it's generally working very nicely.  Winetricks in particular is making the transfer quite easy, as the programs that I couldn't easily replace seem to operate largely without a hitch.

Unfortunately, one of the programs I couldn't get working quite right is a digital illustration program called Paint Tool Sai.  It opens fine and the functions are all present... except the pressure sensitivity.  I suspect it's more than likely that SAI doesn't know how to interpret the native Wacom drivers.  My Paint appears to be lacking in some useful features that are part of my workflow, and GiMP hasn't impressed me much as a tool for illustration; if possible I'd prefer to use this particular program.

As of current, I was considering installing the Bamboo drivers into winetricks, but I'm not in any way certain that this is sound.  Is this a feasible solution to this issue, or should I try another workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but since the issue is still not solved by Wine, people will probably be still googling what to do, so...

I've asked people at PlayOnLinux to make a special Wine build with the fixed pen pressure issue. So, what you need to do is:

- install PlayOnLinux
- go to Tools->Manage Wine Versions and install the version named "1.5.5-SAI"
- go to File->Install->Install a non-listed program and install SAI
- in PlayOnLinux, select SAI, click Configure, then under Wine Version, select 1.5.5-SAI
- in PlayOnLinux, select SAI again, click Open the directory, open file misc.ini, change TabletMouseSimulation = 0 to TabletMouseSimulation = 1 (otherwise the pen will twitch about on it's own)
- in PlayOnLinux, select SAI and click play :) Pen pressure should work now.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you THANK YOU VERY MUCH. PaintTool SAI **was** the only thing holding my girlfriend back from using Linux, as she's a graphics artist, and thanks to your post, she now can enjoy pressure sensitivity in a great desktop :) But how did these guys make it? Where did you ask? I wanted to thank them too! <3

Comment: Do you know if the fix can be ported to wine proper or does the fix cause other issues?

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.winehq.org/TabletSupport should be having most up to date information

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and consists basically solely of a link.

Comment: And said link is dead. This is why we dislike link-only answers.